# Comparison between A and B

Tags: sentence-structure, comparison

When comparing two things, such as A and B. If A is better than B, can I say "it's A for B"?

Comment: Will you please give an example? The way you asked, I tend to say that you should not say "it's A for B".

Answer (score 1):

I feel what you may be trying to say is “A over B”, as in “I’d choose A over B”.

“A for B” doesn’t sound right for a comparison, and makes me think more of substitution, i.e. substituting “A for B”.